# Unexpected EOF while looking for

Tags: bash, eof

```
#!/bin/bash

STOP=0
ARRAY=( "[0;30m             kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m ___ ____"
        "[0;30m      kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m / __/ ___|"
        "[0;30m     kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m | |  \___\"
      )
IDX=0
MAX=${#ARRAY[@]}
while [ $STOP -eq 0 ]; do
echo ${ARRAY[${IDX}]}
let IDX=IDX+1
if [ $IDX -eq $MAX ]; then
    IDX=0
fi
sleep 1
done
```

This is the area of where the error appears but i cant find what I missed.
And this is the error:
    line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
    line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well the last `"` is escaped with a `\"` you also may need to escape the internal `"`

Comment: The fact that everything after the first quote is red should be an indicator of something wrong.

Comment: And that's why using an editor/IDE with syntax highlighting is usually a good idea. ;)

Comment: http://shellcheck.net should be enough for you...

Answer (score 0):

You have embedded `\` characters, use single quotes instead of double quotes.  You cannot 'escape' a single quote (in bash), so it is safer (unfortunately many syntax highlighters, including this one, don't know that).

You are using very old syntax considering you are using bash.

It is a bad idea to user UPPERCASE variable names because they can collide with names that the shell uses.

Every time you fail to indent your code a kitten dies.

```
#!/bin/bash

stop=0
array=( '[0;30m             kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m ___ ____'
        '[0;30m      kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m / __/ ___|'
        '[0;30m     kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk    kkkkkkkkkkkk [01;32m | |  \___\'
      )
idx=0
max=${#array[@]}

while (( $stop == 0 ))
do
    echo ${array[${idx}]}
    (( idx=idx+1 ))

    if (( $idx == $max ))
    then
        idx=0
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```